# Ocultar varias letras de una palabra en CSS

Tags: css

Me gustaría saber como ocultar varias letras de una palabra concreta. Por ejemplo: pelo, y que solo aparezca de forma visual "pe" sin el "lo". Y si hay otra forma sin utilizar el comando p. Ya que las palabras se tendrian que coger de una lista larga y el comando p no funcionaría.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tres preguntas iguales???? mira todos los links que te pase...